# Infinispan : Statistics are enabled while attribute 'available' is set to false

Tags: wildfly, infinispan, second-level-cache

I get the following exception when starting Wildfly configured for second level cache. I have enabled second level cache in `persistence.xml`. If I remove below `property` it starts properly. what is the problem with the below configuration ?

**persistence.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics" value= "true"/>
```

**standalone.xml** (default one that comes in wildfly)

```
    <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan">
        <local-cache name="entity">
            <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
            <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
            <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="local-query">
            <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
            <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
    </cache-container>
```

**exception :**

> Statistics are enabled while attribute 'available' is set to false.

**logs**

```
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:242)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: Unable to start region factory
        at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:418)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:28)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:20)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000372: **Statistics are enabled while attribute 'available' is set to false.**
        at org.infinispan.configuration.cache.JMXStatisticsConfigurationBuilder.validate(JMXStatisticsConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder.validate(ConfigurationBuilder.java:203)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder.build(ConfigurationBuilder.java:246)
        at org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder.build(ConfigurationBuilder.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.defineGenericDataTypeCacheConfigurations(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:636)
        at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:394)
        ... 19 more
```

Comment: What wildfly version? Can you make sure your app does not ship Infinispan jars within it?

Comment: it is 10.1 final version. And my app does not have any infinispan  specific jars. Any other thoughts ?

Answer (score 4):

As the error message explains, the statistics are enabled (through the `hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics=true` in your `persistence.xml`), but the cache container statistics is not available because it is not enabled by default.

Wildfly 10 (and JBoss EAP 7) validates the hibernate statistics when the application starts (see [JMXStatisticsConfigurationBuilder:64](http://www.lookatsrc.com/source/org/infinispan/configuration/cache/JMXStatisticsConfigurationBuilder.java?a=org.infinispan:infinispan-core)). As the application statistics is enabled, but the container statistics is not available, the exception is raised.

To activate the cache container statistics, you need to add **`statistics-enabled="true"`** in your `cache-container` and `local-cache` configuration:

```
<cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query"
        module="org.hibernate.infinispan"
        statistics-enabled="true">
        <local-cache name="entity"
            statistics-enabled="true">
            <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
            <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
            <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="local-query"
            statistics-enabled="true">
            <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
            <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="timestamps"
            statistics-enabled="true"/>
</cache-container>
```